# Spring register objects destroy method

Tags: java, spring

I'm currently converting XML spring config to Java annotations, and I've ran into a little bit of an annoying situation.

I need to create 3 beans, which use the same class internally, but need to be seperate instances. However, these internal beans need to register their shutdown method with Spring.

I can't think how to do this without creating 9 beans in java (which is fine, but it seems a little bit wrong to be polluting the class like this)

In XML config it looks something like this:

```
<bean class="outer1">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="middle">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="inner" />
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean class="outer2">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="middle">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="inner" />
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean class="outer3">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="middle">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="inner" />
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Do you really want `middle` and `inner` to be beans? If not you just create them in your `getXXX` method

Comment: Why not just calling the inner beans' shutdown method on the outer beans' spring registered destroy method?

Comment: A possible solution here http://shekhargulati.com/2010/10/30/spring-scoped-proxy-beans-an-alternative-to-method-injection/

Comment: @StavSaad Because the interface that inner/middle implement don't have shutdown on them.

Comment: @talex because I need their shutdown methods to be called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig{
    @Bean(destroyMethod="cleanup")
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public Inner inner(){
        return new Inner();
    }


    @Bean(destroyMethod="cleanup")
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public Middle middle(){
        return new Middle(inner());
    }

    @Bean
    public Outer outer1(){
        return new Outer(middle());
    }


    @Bean
    public Outer outer2(){
        return new Outer(middle());
    }


    @Bean
    public Outer outer3(){
        return new Outer(middle());
    }
}
```

From [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-prototype):

> The non-singleton, prototype scope of bean deployment results in the
> creation of a new bean instance every time a request for that specific
> bean is made.

This means that every call to the middle() and inner() method creates a new instance of your bean.